# PHP Post is not setting value on jquery form submit

Tags: php, html, jquery, sweetalert

PHP Form

```
<form id="f1" action="welcome.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP Post

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
      echo 'You have clicked submit button';
  }
}
```

Here the value is printing. But when we submit the form using the jquery:

```
 $('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) form.submit();
    });
});
```

The echo value is not printing. How can I print the echo value using jquery form submit?

SweetAlert:
https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Comment: why use jquery without do nothing?

Comment: The server-side code is looking for the clicked button, but the jQuery code isn't invoking a button click, it's invoking a form submit.  What's the goal here?  The UX is identical between the two, so what are you trying to accomplish by using this jQuery code?

Comment: @Simone Rossaini: Actually I am using sweetalert confirm on submit button, there I am facing this issue.

Comment: `$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {        
   $("#f1").submit();
});` makes no sense. This will just cause the form to be submitted twice (because clicking the button will cause the browser to trigger the submit anyway, without needing extra code).

Comment: Maybe don't check for `btnSubmit` on the server and just handle the submitted form as-is?

Comment: add to your jquery : `e.preventdefault();` that will prevent double submit.

Comment: Now, I have updated my question.

Comment: What does `swal` do? Where do you submit the form using AJAX?

Comment: Swal is just Modal confirm. I have added library for reference

Comment: @Dylan: Take a step back and define the goal here.  The client-side code is handling the button click and then submitting the form.  Does the server-side code need to know which button was clicked?  Or should it just handle the submitted form?  What's the goal?

Comment: your on click is being used for nothing. very strange.

Answer (score 0):

`btnSubmit` is not on your `$_POST` variable;
only type text (in your case) is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    print_r($_POST); 
}
```

To see if you get value for `btnSubmit`. Pretty sure you need to attach value for it to set a key/value pair in the $_POST.

The easiest way to make this work is to change your button to this:

```
<input name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The security issues presented when you don't check input are huge. Just check out Johnny Tables (https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I have multiple forms on the same page. That's why I am using isset($_POST['btnSubmit']).

Comment: That's why you need a value for the button. It's easier if you look for that